# Needed help to access XML data present on a different domain

Tags: javascript, xml, json, xmlhttprequest

I have a webservice present on a different domain(basically an authentication servlet) and it returns data in XML format, so whenever I try to make an XMLHttpRequest object and call this service I run across of the Access-Control-Allow-Origin problem as this data is present on a different domain. I also tried using JSONP, but as the service returned an XML, this did not work. So do you have any suggestions on what I can do.(like maybe change the MIME type of the returned data in the JSONP call, if thats even possible) Also the worst part is that I cannot change the return type of the service from XML to JSON.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Domain 1: The domain which loads the javascript that makes the xml request

Domain 2: The domain from which you are trying to get xml

You have to set Access-Control-Allow-Origin option in the response header of Domain 2. The value of it should be the url of the Domain 1.

Comment: it makes some sense, so do you have any code through which I can do this, means I know how to set the header eg. xhr.setRequestHeader("",""), but which attributes should I supply. Thanks for replying

Comment: I have done it once. But I use Pyramid web framework. Which framework are you using?

Comment: You have to do it in the server side. Hence I was saying response header. Not request header

Comment: ok, but I have no access to the server-side code, and dont think will also get access, also I am not using any framework.